# Is there a function in PHP similar to call_user_func but more like Tcl's eval?

Tags: php, eval, tcl

*Note: I don't think this question has much to do with PHP's `eval`.*

In Tcl, `eval` takes a list, using the first item as the function (proc) name, and the rest of the items as arguments, e.g.

```
eval [list foobar arg1 arg2 arg3]
```

is equivalent to

```
foobar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

In PHP, both `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array` require at least two parameters: (1) the function name, and (2) either the arguments or an array of the arguments, respectively.

**Is there a similar function in PHP that takes only one parameter?**

I wrote my own, as shown below, but I'd prefer a native method.

```
function call_user_array(array $a) {
    return call_user_func_array(array_shift($a), $a);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hints.

<strike>*P.S. Not sure if "lambda" has anything to do with this but the word comes to mind for some reason: would someone more knowledgeable please remove the tag if it's not actually relevant, as well as this note? Thanks again!*</strike>

Comment: Technically, `eval` evaluates a script. The magic is that `list` constructs lists that are also scripts that correspond to single substitution-free commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing built-in to do that. Since it can be implemented in one line (just like you did it) there's also not much reason to consider including one.